# displaying columns side by side for a variable in R

Tags: r

How can I show the three values of "disp" for a particular cylinder? Only one column is getting displayed. I am expecting three columns for each cylinder. Any suggestions?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% arrange(desc(disp)) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice_head(n = 3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, disp)) + geom_col() +facet_wrap(. ~ cyl)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by three values of "disp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Position_dodge` or `Position_dodge2`

```
mtcars |> arrange(desc(disp)) |> group_by(cyl) |> slice_head(n = 3) |> 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, disp)) + geom_col(aes(fill = disp), position = position_dodge2())
```

Then you can fill in the bars with whatever variable.

[image]